# Unable to generate a URL for the named route admin_sonata_classification_category_create

Tags: classification, sonata-admin, symfony-2.7

I'm done of installing calassification bundle wiht this error :

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin_sonata_classification_category_create" as such route does not exist.") in SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig at line 39.

ps: I used this steps : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/classification/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html

Comment: Can we have a look to your AppKernel.php file ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On a new project, I encountered the same issue. I fixed it when I put below code in my routing.yml file

```
_sonata_admin:
  resource: .
  type: sonata_admin
  prefix: /admin
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Alexandre T's answer: my complete routing.yml file looked like this.

```
admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

Comment: Where did you add this exactly ?